# What '$' means when scaning if char in strings are certain symbols?

Tags: c++, string, char, postfix-notation, associative

im studying c++, and im stuck on understanding certain line of code.

```
bool IsOperator(char C)
{
if(C == '+' || C == '-' || C == '*' || C == '/' || C== '$')
    return true;

return false;
}
```

The program im trying to understand scans if the char in string is operator. If yes, get him a number. Inflix to postflix is the problem here.

```
int IsRightAssociative(char op)
{
    if(op == '$') return true;
return false;
}
```

Here is what i cant understand, where the program finds the '$' char if i write ((3+2)*3-5)*2??

I will attach the whole code for better understanding

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stack>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

    // Function to convert Infix expression to postfix 
    string InfixToPostfix(string expression);

// Function to verify whether an operator has higher precedence over other
int HasHigherPrecedence(char operator1, char operator2);

// Function to verify whether a character is operator symbol or not. 
bool IsOperator(char C);

// Function to verify whether a character is alphanumeric chanaract (letter or numeric digit) or not. 
bool IsOperand(char C);

int main() 
{
string expression; 
cout<<"Enter Infix Expression \n";
getline(cin,expression);
string postfix = InfixToPostfix(expression);
cout<<"Output = "<<postfix<<"\n";
}

// Function to evaluate Postfix expression and return output
string InfixToPostfix(string expression)
{
// Declaring a Stack from Standard template library in C++. 
stack<char> S;
string postfix = ""; // Initialize postfix as empty string.
for(int i = 0;i< expression.length();i++) {

    // Scanning each character from left. 
    // If character is a delimitter, move on. 
    if(expression[i] == ' ' || expression[i] == ',') continue; 

    // If character is operator, pop two elements from stack, perform operation and push the result back. 
    else if(IsOperator(expression[i])) 
    {
        while(!S.empty() && S.top() != '(' && HasHigherPrecedence(S.top(),expression[i]))
        {
            postfix+= S.top();
            S.pop();
        }
        S.push(expression[i]);
    }
    // Else if character is an operand
    else if(IsOperand(expression[i]))
    {
        postfix +=expression[i];
    }

    else if (expression[i] == '(') 
    {
        S.push(expression[i]);
    }

    else if(expression[i] == ')') 
    {
        while(!S.empty() && S.top() !=  '(') {
            postfix += S.top();
            S.pop();
        }
        S.pop();
    }
}

while(!S.empty()) {
    postfix += S.top();
    S.pop();
}

return postfix;
}

// Function to verify whether a character is english letter or numeric     digit. 
// We are assuming in this solution that operand will be a single character
bool IsOperand(char C) 
{
if(C >= '0' && C <= '9') return true;
if(C >= 'a' && C <= 'z') return true;
if(C >= 'A' && C <= 'Z') return true;
return false;
}

// Function to verify whether a character is operator symbol or not. 
bool IsOperator(char C)
{
if(C == '+' || C == '-' || C == '*' || C == '/' || C== '$')
    return true;

return false;
}

// Function to verify whether an operator is right associative or not. 
int IsRightAssociative(char op)
{
if(op == '$') return true;
return false;
}

// Function to get weight of an operator. An operator with higher weight     will have higher precedence. 
int GetOperatorWeight(char op)
{
int weight = -1; 
switch(op)
{
case '+':
case '-':
    weight = 1;
case '*':
case '/':
    weight = 2;
case '$':
    weight = 3;
}
return weight;
}

// Function to perform an operation and return output. 
int HasHigherPrecedence(char op1, char op2)
{
int op1Weight = GetOperatorWeight(op1);
int op2Weight = GetOperatorWeight(op2);

// If operators have equal precedence, return true if they are left associative. 
// return false, if right associative. 
// if operator is left-associative, left one should be given priority. 
if(op1Weight == op2Weight)
{
    if(IsRightAssociative(op1)) return false;
    else return true;
}
return op1Weight > op2Weight ?  true: false;
}
```

So if anyone can help i will be very glad :(.

Comment: In this case, there is no regex or anything like that. It literally means the dollar character. The author is using that to represent some operation, although what isn't clear. (And as a piece of advice for future questions, it is best not to paste in a huge bit of code, but strip it down to a [minimal example](http://sscce.org/), but don't worry about editing this one.)

Comment: thank you for your time! i will be more carefull